# L€€CH€$! D€AṬH ỊṢ ṢOOṄ! (Length Mapping)

Tags: code-golf, array, jelly

<sub>The title is valid Jelly Code which has the same output as `L€€` except printed twice.</sub>

#### Background

<sup>You can skip this section without losing ability to complete the challenge</sup>

Some operations in Jelly try to convert its argument to a list first before applying the operation. One example is `€`, the mapping quick. This sometimes leads to unintended output.

For the program `L€` and input 5, the Jelly interpreter tries to find the length of every element of the list 5. Since 5 is not a list, Jelly converts it to the list [1,2,3,4,5]. Then the length of every element is output: `[1,1,1,1,1]`. Note that every integer has length `1`. If e.g. `10` was present, it would become `1`, not `2` (the length in digits).

For the program `L€€` and input 5, the Jelly interpreter tries to find the length of every element of every element of the list 5. Since 5 is not a list, Jelly converts it to the list `[1,2,3,4,5]`. Now the interpreter tries to find the length of every element of every element of the list `[1,2,3,4,5]`. Every element is not a list, so Jelly converts them to lists in the same manner: `[[1],[1,2],[1,2,3],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4,5]]`. The length of every sub-element is output as `[[1],[1,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1,1]]`

#### Task

Your task is to find the output of the Jelly program `L` followed by `€` repeated `a` times, with input `b`, where `a` and `b` are positive integers equal to your program/function's inputs.

A way to do this is:

Starting with the input `b`, do the following `a` times:

- For every integer that the program sees, replace it with the range of the integer (where `range(x) := [1,2,3,...,x-1,x]`)

Finally, replace every integer with 1.

#### Test Cases

```
a
b
output
- - - - -
1
1
[1]
- - - - -
1
2
[1, 1]
- - - - -
1
3
[1, 1, 1]
- - - - -
1
4
[1, 1, 1, 1]
- - - - -
1
5
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
- - - - -
1
6
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
- - - - -
2
1
[[1]]
- - - - -
2
2
[[1], [1, 1]]
- - - - -
2
3
[[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]
- - - - -
2
4
[[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1]]
- - - - -
2
5
[[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
- - - - -
2
6
[[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
- - - - -
3
1
[[[1]]]
- - - - -
3
2
[[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]]]
- - - - -
3
3
[[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]], [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]]
- - - - -
3
4
[[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]], [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1]], [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1]]]
- - - - -
3
5
[[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]], [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1]], [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1]], [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]]
- - - - -
3
6
[[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]], [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1]], [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1]], [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]], [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]]
- - - - -
4
1
[[[[1]]]]
- - - - -
4
2
[[[[1]]], [[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]]]]
- - - - -
4
3
[[[[1]]], [[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]]], [[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]], [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]]]
- - - - -
4
4
[[[[1]]], [[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]]], [[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]], [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]], [[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]], [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1]], [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1]]]]
- - - - -
4
5
[[[[1]]], [[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]]], [[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]], [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]], [[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]], [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1]], [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1]]], [[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]], [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1]], [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1]], [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]]]
- - - - -
4
6
[[[[1]]], [[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]]], [[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]], [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]], [[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]], [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1]], [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1]]], [[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]], [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1]], [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1]], [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]], [[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]], [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1]], [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1]], [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]], [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]]]
- - - - -
5
1
[[[[[1]]]]]
- - - - -
5
2
[[[[[1]]]], [[[[1]]], [[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]]]]]
- - - - -
5
3
[[[[[1]]]], [[[[1]]], [[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]]]], [[[[1]]], [[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]]], [[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]], [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]]]]
- - - - -
5
4
[[[[[1]]]], [[[[1]]], [[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]]]], [[[[1]]], [[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]]], [[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]], [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]]], [[[[1]]], [[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]]], [[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]], [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]], [[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]], [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1]], [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1]]]]]
- - - - -
5
5
[[[[[1]]]], [[[[1]]], [[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]]]], [[[[1]]], [[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]]], [[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]], [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]]], [[[[1]]], [[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]]], [[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]], [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]], [[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]], [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1]], [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1]]]], [[[[1]]], [[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]]], [[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]], [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]], [[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]], [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1]], [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1]]], [[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]], [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1]], [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1]], [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]]]]
- - - - -
5
6
[[[[[1]]]], [[[[1]]], [[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]]]], [[[[1]]], [[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]]], [[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]], [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]]], [[[[1]]], [[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]]], [[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]], [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]], [[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]], [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1]], [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1]]]], [[[[1]]], [[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]]], [[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]], [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]], [[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]], [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1]], [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1]]], [[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]], [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1]], [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1]], [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]]], [[[[1]]], [[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]]], [[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]], [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]], [[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]], [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1]], [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1]]], [[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]], [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1]], [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1]], [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]], [[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]], [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1]], [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1]], [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]], [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]]]]
- - - - -
6
1
[[[[[[1]]]]]]
- - - - -
6
2
[[[[[[1]]]]], [[[[[1]]]], [[[[1]]], [[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]]]]]]
- - - - -
6
3
[[[[[[1]]]]], [[[[[1]]]], [[[[1]]], [[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]]]]], [[[[[1]]]], [[[[1]]], [[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]]]], [[[[1]]], [[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]]], [[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]], [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]]]]]
- - - - -
6
4
[[[[[[1]]]]], [[[[[1]]]], [[[[1]]], [[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]]]]], [[[[[1]]]], [[[[1]]], [[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]]]], [[[[1]]], [[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]]], [[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]], [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]]]], [[[[[1]]]], [[[[1]]], [[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]]]], [[[[1]]], [[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]]], [[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]], [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]]], [[[[1]]], [[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]]], [[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]], [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]], [[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]], [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1]], [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1]]]]]]
- - - - -
6
5
[[[[[[1]]]]], [[[[[1]]]], [[[[1]]], [[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]]]]], [[[[[1]]]], [[[[1]]], [[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]]]], [[[[1]]], [[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]]], [[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]], [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]]]], [[[[[1]]]], [[[[1]]], [[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]]]], [[[[1]]], [[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]]], [[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]], [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]]], [[[[1]]], [[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]]], [[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]], [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]], [[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]], [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1]], [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1]]]]], [[[[[1]]]], [[[[1]]], [[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]]]], [[[[1]]], [[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]]], [[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]], [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]]], [[[[1]]], [[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]]], [[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]], [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]], [[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]], [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1]], [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1]]]], [[[[1]]], [[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]]], [[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]], [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]], [[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]], [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1]], [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1]]], [[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]], [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1]], [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1]], [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]]]]]
- - - - -
6
6
[[[[[[1]]]]], [[[[[1]]]], [[[[1]]], [[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]]]]], [[[[[1]]]], [[[[1]]], [[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]]]], [[[[1]]], [[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]]], [[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]], [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]]]], [[[[[1]]]], [[[[1]]], [[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]]]], [[[[1]]], [[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]]], [[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]], [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]]], [[[[1]]], [[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]]], [[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]], [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]], [[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]], [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1]], [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1]]]]], [[[[[1]]]], [[[[1]]], [[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]]]], [[[[1]]], [[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]]], [[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]], [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]]], [[[[1]]], [[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]]], [[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]], [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]], [[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]], [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1]], [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1]]]], [[[[1]]], [[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]]], [[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]], [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]], [[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]], [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1]], [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1]]], [[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]], [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1]], [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1]], [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]]]], [[[[[1]]]], [[[[1]]], [[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]]]], [[[[1]]], [[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]]], [[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]], [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]]], [[[[1]]], [[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]]], [[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]], [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]], [[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]], [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1]], [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1]]]], [[[[1]]], [[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]]], [[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]], [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]], [[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]], [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1]], [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1]]], [[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]], [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1]], [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1]], [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]]], [[[[1]]], [[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]]], [[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]], [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]], [[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]], [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1]], [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1]]], [[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]], [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1]], [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1]], [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]], [[[1]], [[1], [1, 1]], [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1]], [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1]], [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]], [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]]]]]
```

#### Rules

- `a` and `b` are restricted to positive integers
- Your program or function may take `a` and `b` in any order and in any standard input format
- The output should be a depth-a list or string representation of such a list
- The output should be returned through any standard output format.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code **in each language** wins!

Comment: I would disallow builtins that eval a string as Jelly code (looking at you, Jelly)

Comment: @StepHen The creation of the string takes too many bytes as compared to repeating the Range function, so I will leave the capability to eval as permitted.

Comment: Fort clarification: The length of any integer is `1`, not the length of its decimal expansion?

Comment: @Titus Yes. I will clarify this in the question.

Comment: The title can be golfed to `L€€CH!DṬHỊṢṄ!` (or maybe `L€€Ṅ`) btw...

Answer (score 13):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 bytes

```
R¡Ṡ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ARoA5f9qZWxsef//UsKh4bmg/8OHxZLhuZj//zP/Mg)

Takes input in reverse order.
-2 bytes thanks to fireflame.
-1 byte thanks to Dennis

## Explanation

```
R¡Ṡ  Main link
 ¡   Repeat <first argument> times
R    Range (generates range, and vectorizes on lists)
  Ṡ  Sign (converts all numbers to 1 because they are all positive)
```

Comment: You can make use of implicit input by removing `⁴` and taking arguments in reverse order.

Comment: @fireflame241 oh ok thanks! -2 bytes then by removing the `^3` as well

Comment: You can use the sign atom `Ṡ` instead of molding.

Comment: Of course Jelly would be unbeatable here...

Comment: @Erik True, but I'm surprised that neither `L` nor `€` appears in this solution.

Answer (score 11):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 49 bytes

<sup>-1 thanks to [Jonathan Allan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/53748/jonathan-allan)</sup>

```python
f=lambda a,b:1>>a or[0]*b and f(a,b-1)+[f(a-1,b)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P802JzE3KSVRIVEnycrQzi5RIb8o2iBWK0khMS9FIU0DKKxrqKkdDWTpGuokacb@T8svUkhUyMxTKErMS0/VMNQx17Ti4gSJJmGIchYUZeaVKCTCWUlwFthoTThXXVcBCtX/AwA)

This problem seemed like it could be written in the form of a doubly recursive function, subtracting one from each parameter. The key idea is that the sequence can be related as follows:

```python
f(0,b) = 1
f(a,0) = []
f(a,b) = f(a,b-1) + [f(a-1,b)]
```

However writing a recursive function like this is pretty tricky, since `1` is a truthy value and `[]` is a falsy value, so we need two short-circuiting keywords (`and` and `or`).

A less golfed version might look like:

```python
lambda a,b:int(a<1)or[1,[]][b<1]and f(a,b-1)+[f(a-1,b)]
```

However we can use the trick that `1>>a` gives `1` if a is zero, and `0` otherwise, and that we can return a truthy value if `b>0` and an empty list otherwise by doing `[0]*b`.

Comment: Save one with `or[0]*b and` in place of `or[0][:b]and`.

Answer (score 9):

## Mathematica, 17 bytes

```
1^Range~Nest~##&
```

Takes `b` then `a`.

[Try it on Wolfram Sandbox](https://sandbox.open.wolframcloud.com/)

#### How?

```
1^Range~Nest~##&

  Range             (* Range function; generates {1..<input>} *)
       ~Nest~##     (* Apply it on <input 1> <input 2> times *)
                    (* Mathematica automatically maps Range onto integers *)
1^                  (* Raise those to the exponent of 1; make everything 1 *)
```

#### Usage

```
1^Range~Nest~##&[4, 2]
```

> `{{1}, {1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1}}`

Answer (score 4):

## [Gaia](https://github.com/splcurran/Gaia), 7 bytes

```
ẏ¦”@)⊃e
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0/MTPz//@Gu/kPLHjXMddB81NWc@v@/MZcJAA)

`ẏ¦` does just about the same thing here as `L€` in Jelly. `ẏ` is "is positive?" and `¦` is map, which also implicitly casts an integer to the range 1 .. n before mapping. And since we're dealing with only integers >= 1, `ẏ` will result in `1` for each.

```
ẏ¦”      Push the string "ẏ¦"
   @)    Push the first input+1
     ⊃   Repeat the last character of the string until it's input+1 characters long.
      e  Eval it.
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>57</s> 55 bytes

<sup>-1 byte thanks to Jakob</sup>
<sup>-1 byte thanks to notjagan</sup>

```python
f=lambda a,b:[1]*b*(a<2)or[f(a-1,i+1)for i in range(b)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcExDoAgDADAr3SkiAO4GX0JYShRtIkWQlh8fb1r37irBNWyP/Tmg4BcXqNPNltDW8DaYzE0e8eTx1I7MLBAJ7lOkzFp6ywDillcQP0B)

Answer (score 3):

## PHP, 134 bytes

```php
for($r=[$argv[2]];$argv[1]--;)($w=array_walk_recursive)($r,function(&$n){$n=range(1,$n);});$w($r,function(&$n){$n=1;});print_r($r[0]);
```

There may be a shorter approach than the literal one ... but it´s working at least.

Run with `-nr` and provide `a` and `b` as arguments or [try it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0a829eba8eb5496e2171da45150dd2b59f749a0c).

---

For output as in the examples, use `echo strtr(preg_replace('#"\d":#','',json_encode($r[0],JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK)),"{}","[]");` (as I do in the TiO) instead of `print_r($r[0]);`.

Answer (score 3):

### JavaScript (ES6), 95 bytes

```js
f=(a,b,r=/\d+/g)=>a--?f(a,b.replace(r,s=>`[${[...Array(+s)].map((_,i)=>++i)}]`)):b.replace(r,1)
```

```html
<div oninput=o.textContent=f(a.value,b.value)><input type=number min=0 value=0 id=a><input type=number min=0 value=0 id=b><pre wrap id=o>1
```

I/O is with strings. The best I could do nonrecursively was 100 bytes:

```
(a,b)=>[...Array(-~a)].reduce(r=>r.replace(/\d+/g,a--?s=>`[${[...Array(+s)].map((_,i)=>++i)}]`:1),b)
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 21 bytes

```
,1{t+₁I&⟦₁ᵐ⁾;I}ⁱ⁽ṡᵐ⁾c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/X8ewukT7UVOjp9qj@cuA9MOtEx417rP2rH3UuPFR496HOxdCRJL//4820VEwjv0fBQA)

Conceptually simple, but keeping track of the right level to map the 'range' `⟦` predicate at, takes up almost half the bytes. :(

```
                 % Implicit input, list [a, b]
,1               % Append iteration index 1 to the list
{           }ⁱ⁽  % Do this iteratively a times, with [b, i] as the initial input
 t+₁I            % Increment iteration index, let this be I
     &⟦₁ᵐ⁾       % Map the "range from 1 to input" predicate on the first part of input
                 %   (b in the first iteration), at depth given by (old) iteration index
          ;I     % Append the incremented index to this, this is the input to next iteration
ṡᵐ⁾              % Take the sign of each element, mapped at depth given by final I
c                % "Concatenate" to remove extra surrounding array
```

And a recursive solution, just for the heck of it:

#### 24 bytes

```
{t0&hṡᵐ|t-₁L&h⟦₁ᵐ;Lz↰ᵐ}c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/v7rEQC3j4c6FD7dOqCnRfdTU6KOW8Wj@MiADKGLtU/WobQOQUZv8/3@0iY6Ccez/KAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 12 bytes

```
⁴Ṿ;”L;”€ẋ³¤V
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9R45aHO/dZP2qY6wMiHjWtebir@9DmQ0vC/v//b/TfGAA)

Just to get things started. I'm pretty sure it would be shorter if I actually did it the way I'm supposed to, so I'm working on that (inb4 ninja'd by someone)

## Explanation

```
⁴Ṿ;”L;”€ẋ³¤V  Main link
 Ṿ            Generate Jelly code that will evaluate to
⁴             The second input
  ;           Concatenate with
   ”L         "L"
     ;        Concatenate with
      ”€ẋ³¤   Niladic Expression
      ”€      "€"
        ẋ     Repeated                times
         ³             <first input>
           V  Jelly-eval it
```